# Synonym function call for ::new((void*)p)T(value);

Tags: c++11, stl, new-operator, allocator

I am trying to write my own `Allocator` which can be used in STL. That far I could almost successfully finish but with one function I have my problem:

The `Allocator` used in STL should provide the function `construct` [example from a standard allocator using `new` & `delete`]:

```
// initialize elements of allocated storage p with value value
void construct (T* p, const T& value)
{
    ::new((void*)p)T(value);
}
```

I am stuck how to rewrite this using my own function which replaces the `new` keyword initializing it with the `value`.

This function `construct` is for example used in this code: `fileLines.push_back( fileLine );`

where

```
MyVector<MyString>      fileLines;
MyString                fileLine;
```

These are my `typedefs` where I use my own `Allocator`:

```
template <typename T> using MyVector = std::vector<T, Allocator<T>>;
using MyString = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Allocator<char>>;
```

I am confused because here is allocated a `pointer` to `T` which can be for example [when I understood it correctly]  `MySstring`.

Do I understand it correctly that the pointer - allocated by `new` - will have 10 bytes, when `value` is `123456789` and then the provided `value` is copied to the new pointer?

**My question:**

How to rewrite the one line of code using my own function? For me the *difficult* point is how to get the length of `value` [which can have any type] in order I can correctly determinate the length of the allocated block and how to *copy* it in order it works for all possible types `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `new` operator in the `construct` function does not allocate anything at all, it's a *placement new* call, which takes an already allocated chunk of memory (which needs to have been previously allocated some way, and at least as large as `sizeof(T)`) and initializes it as a `T` object by calling the constructor of `T`, pretending that the memory pointed to by `p` is a `T` object.

Comment: This is quite confusing for most people at first. To explain, in this particular context, “placement new” actually means “calling a class’ constructor”: C++ lacks a dedicated syntax for calling a constructor on a memory address (unlike for calling a *destructor*, which does have a dedicated syntax, via `p->~T()`). Placement new’s default overload, however, does just this.

Answer (score 2):

`::new int(7)` calls the default `new` operator, gets some memory big enough for an `int`, and constructs an `int` with the value `7` in it.

`::new(ptr) int(7)` takes a `void*` called `ptr`, and constructs an `int` with the value `7` in it.  This is called "placement new".

The important part is what is missing from the second paragraph.  It does not create space, but rather constructs an object in some existing space.

It is like saying `ptr->T::T()` `ptr->int::int(7)` where we "call the constructor`of`int`on the memory location of`ptr`, except`ptr->T::T()`or`ptr->int::int(7)`are not valid syntaxes.  Placement`new` is the way to explicitly call a constructor in C++.

Similarly, `ptr->~T()` or `ptr->~int()` will call the destructor on the object located at `ptr` (however, there is no `~int` so that is an error, unless `int` is a template or dependent type, in which case it is a pseudo-destructor and the call it ignored instead of generating an error).

It is very rare that you want to change `construct` from the default implementation in an allocator.  You might do this if your allocator wants to track creation of objects and attach the information about their arguments, without intrusively modifying the constructor.  But this is a corner case.